# No container in JSONSerializer

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is failing in my application (from `JSONSerializer` in `ember-data`):

```
transformFor: function(attributeType, skipAssertion) {
    var transform = this.container.lookup('transform:' + attributeType);
    Ember.assert("Unable to find transform for '" + attributeType + "'", skipAssertion || !!transform);
    return transform;
}
```

This is the error:

[image]

There is indeed no container. Why? Should I define it? How?

This is my adapter:

```
SettingsApp.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    bulkCommit: false,
    namespace: SettingsApp.config.API_NAMESPACE,
    host: SettingsApp.apiUrl,
    serializer: SettingsApp.MetaRESTSerializer.create(),
    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
        var ajaxPromise = this._super(url, type, hash);
        if (DEBUG) { console.log('>>>>> REQUEST > %s:%s > hash=%o ajaxPromise=%o', type, url, hash, ajaxPromise); }
        ajaxPromise.then(function(json){
            if (DEBUG) { console.log('>>>>> REPLY   > %s:%s > %o', type, url, json); }
        });
        return ajaxPromise;
    }
});
```

And this is the serializer (nothing special):

```
SettingsApp.MetaRESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id',
    extractMeta: function(store, type, payload) {
        // TODO: standard implementation. Check with backend to implement this for good
        if (payload && payload.meta) {
            store.metaForType(type, payload.meta);
            delete payload.meta;
        }
    },

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1741), the solution is to do:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({...});
```

And **not** implement serializer in the `DS.RESTAdapter`

```
//serializer: SettingsApp.MetaRESTSerializer.create(),
```